# Round table arrrangement for 13 people using graph theory

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

> 13 Members of a new club ,meet each day for lunch at a round table.
>   They decide to  sit such that every memher has different neighbours at
>   each lunch.How many days can this arrangement last?

By using normal combinatorics we can find that number of days is six.
But I have no idea how to do it using graph theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw the thirteen vertices in a circle.  You can draw six different graphs on these vertices by connecting each vertex to the on next to it, skip one, skip two, etc.  Each graph is a cycle graph and indicates the order around the table for one day if you follow the cycle.

Comment: I cant  guess how we can do this with normal combinatorics. Any hint please?

Comment: @Mahesha999:  as there are $12$ choices for each person's neighbors, the maximum is $6$.  I don't see another easy way to show you can achieve $6$.  My construction works any time the number of people is an odd prime.

Comment: oh thats easy. Also you said: *each graph is a cycle graph*. But I dont see how. For example if there are 6 members then I cannot form a cycle if I keep on connecting every 2nd, 3rd or 4th vertex as can be seen in diagram [here](http://s12.postimg.org/p237ilwql/Capture.png) Also how can we form arrangements of members around table corresponding to these graphs?

Comment: @Mahesha999:  That is why I said it works for the number of people an odd prime.  You won't get back to the original person until you have hit all the others.  That actually works any time the number you count is relatively prime to the number of people.  For example, with 12 people you can count every fifth.  With a prime it works for all smaller numbers.  If there are $n$ people, you get $\frac 12(n-1)$ cycle graphs.  Straighten them out and you have a seating arrangement for each day.  So if $n=7$ we get $1234567, 1357246, 1473625$ as the three arrangements.  You can check that they work.